# How can I use a 4D .*mat (28*28*1*800) and import it to Python and organize it as inputs to a CNN?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a basic question: I have two 4D (.*mat) matrices (28*28*1*800). The last dimension is the number of images and the third dimension is the number of channels. I saved this file in my Python directory.

Also, I setup a CNN by using the Keras library. I need to import these inputs in Python and feed them to the network.

Do you have any solution for my question?

Here is the my network architecture :

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(28,28,1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))


model.add(Conv2DTranspose(10,(3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
```

Also, I write some simple codes to read the mat file:

```
matinput = scipy.io.loadmat('C:\\noisy_Input1.mat')

matoutput = scipy.io.loadmat('C:\\Output1.mat')

datainput = np.array(matinput)
dataoutput= np.array(matoutput)
```

But, I have no idea How can I prepare them and feed to the network.